# Upper bound for slope and the finiteness of Legendre transform

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f$ be a convex function and denote with $f^{*}$ the legendre transform.
Is it true that if $f^*(p)=+\infty$, then $p$ is an upper bound for the slope of $f$?

Do you have that if the slope of $f$ is unbounded, then $f^{*}(p)$ is finite?

What I have so far is if $f^{*}(p)=+\infty$ then $\forall M\in \mathbb{R}$ there exists an $x$ such that $xp-f(x)>M$ hence $p>f'(x)$. But this dus not hold for all x, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not true. The correct conclusion from $f^*(p)=\infty$ is that either

- $(f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)\le p$ for all $a\ne b$, or
- $(f(b)-f(a))/(b-a)\ge p$ for all $a\ne b$

For example, both $f(x)=x/2$ and $f(x)=2x$ have $f^*(1)=\infty$.

Proof of the above alternative: since $x\mapsto px-f(x)$ is unbounded from above and concave, it has to be either increasing or decreasing. $\quad \Box$

By contrapositive: if the slope of $f$ is unbounded from above and unbounded from below, then $f^*$ is finite everywhere.